# react-native-device-info has method check dynamicIsland. Error call API be effected when run app replease (not debug)

Tags: dynamic, react-native-device-info, dynamic-island

[react-native-device-info] has method check dynamicIsland. Error call API be effected when run app replease (not debug)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, Dynamic Island APIs are not out yet (will be out with the iOS 16.1 release). There's no technical APIs to check that should work with release yet